# Error request when I defined the column name

Tags: laravel, postgresql

SQL :

```sql
select distinct b.nom, b.moyenne_pond
from previ.rdt_usine b
join previ.rdt r on (r.id_us=b.id_us)
where st_intersects(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(55.40513629386126, -21.23713970920021), 4326), 32740),b.geom)
and r.annee=2018;
```

PHP :

```php
$query = 'select distinct "b.nom", "b.moyenne_pond" 
        from "previ"."'.$name_table.'" b
        join "previ"."rdt" r on (r.id_us=b.id_us)
        where st_intersects(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(?, ?), 4326), 32740), b.geom)
        and r.annee=?';
$data = $db->select($query, $coord);
//$coord is an array of data
```

When I tried to use my request I have a this : `column "b.nom" doesn't exist`, but when I tried the query in pgAdmin the query is successfull, and you could see that the queries are exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove double quotes and add back tick

```
   $query = 'select distinct `b.nom`, `b.moyenne_pond` 
    from `previ`.`$name_table` as  b
    join `previ`.`rdt` as r on (r.id_us=b.id_us)
    where st_intersects(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(?, ?), 4326), 32740), b.geom)
    and r.annee=?';
```